# Geo Location failure from Chrome

Tags: security, geolocation, chromium

Till recently the javascript api navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition () was working fine in Chrome, but now I get the 'only secure origins allowed' error.

Continues to work fine  in other browsers.

Chromium.org details "secure origins" as localhost, https etc.

Anyone aware if this was a recent change in Chromium security, as it was working without https earlier.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a fairly recent change: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en

Time to add https to your site!

Comment: Thanks BazzaDP...your link and info was exactly  I needed to know....with cut over date April 20....i was earlier worried code changes may have caused problem..yes Https time!